# Regex to format decimal to money using LookAhead and Replace

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

I'm trying to format a decimal into a dot/comma money mask (inverting dot to comma):

`1234567.00` into `1.234.567,00`

I use this regex to format thousands, but I don't know how to change the last dot to a comma:

```
(\d)(?=(\d{3})+[\,\.])
... replace: 
$1.
```

I created this regex which is working: [regexr.com/6vnlh](https://regexr.com/6vnlh)

[image: REGEX - HOW format thousands and CHANGE the LAST DOT to COMMA in brazilian money mask]

[regexr.com/6vnlh](https://regexr.com/6vnlh)

Something like this regex to replace `$*.` but it doesn't work:

```
(\d)(?=(\d{3})+[\,\.])(\d{2})
```

replacing something like that for fixed length number like `(\d)(\d{3}).(\d\d)` but with variable number of groups of thousands:

```
$1.$2,$3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you use Notepad++? E.g. search for `\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:(\.)|,))` and replace with `(?{1},:.)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not change it to something more simple like this; https://regexr.com/6vnnp

```
/(\d)\.(\d{2})([\s\n\|])/gm
```

Instead of trying to approach it complex, you can just look at the end of the number. You can tweak and test it based on your whole raw dataset and test if it's sufficient. That's why I normally do. You make your precision adjustments based on those cases that don't match exactly.

Comment: Because I want to format thousands mainly. Your example doesn't format it thousands. I don't know how to math more one group with cents ("\.\d\d") of value to use it on replace.

Comment: Sometimes it's better not to try all you want to achieve in one round. You can also run the formatting over the whole set twice. It will save you a lot of headaches. Think easy, not smart :). You can do the cents and thousands formatting in 2 separate rounds. This is very common in data sanitisation specialities.

Comment: Yes, I change it with a simple replace after separate the thousands. This regex was improved with lookahead way to replace many thousands in one round. I asked to know if it have some way do it in one round, I don't know how to use the lookahead very well. Thanks for your help

Comment: You cannot really do this without code. You want to capture repeated groups and inject dots in between, which would require if-statements to generate unexisting characters, which regex doesn't support for capture groups. Even if you capture the the groups of 3 digits with positive-negative lookaround, you cannot yes/no insert dots. You can only insert hard-coded dots in the replace result, which will never give you the desired result if you want thousands, millions, billions, and so on. Sorry to not give the answer you hoped for.

Comment: I'm glad with your answer. Thanks